# initialization of GtkImage in c

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm encountering a Segmentation Fault when I try to make a Gtkwidget point to a memory address where I've load a png from file. I want `card[6].image` to display the image I've loaded in  `card[0].image` and the I'd like to remove the same image from  `card[0].image`.

```
struct my_image {

    const char *path;
    GtkWidget *image;
};

void create_window() {

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *headbar;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *hbox_3;
    GtkWidget *hbox_table;
    GtkWidget *hbox_1;
    GtkWidget *hbox_2;
    GtkWidget *about_button;
    GtkWidget *event_box1, *event_box2, *event_box3;

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    headbar = gtk_header_bar_new();
    about_button = gtk_button_new_with_mnemonic("CLick");
    event_box1 = gtk_event_box_new ();
    event_box2 = gtk_event_box_new ();
    event_box3 = gtk_event_box_new ();
    vbox = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 50);   
    hbox_3 = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 35);
    hbox_table = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 35);
    hbox_2= gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
    hbox_1 = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 35);   

    gtk_header_bar_set_title (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), "Myprogram");
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Myprogram");    
    gtk_window_set_titlebar (GTK_WINDOW (window), headbar);
    gtk_header_bar_set_show_close_button (GTK_HEADER_BAR (headbar), TRUE);
    gtk_window_maximize (GTK_WINDOW (window));  

    card[0].path = pile[0];
    card[1].path = pile[1];
    card[2].path = pile[2];

    card[0].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[0].path);
    card[1].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[1].path);
    card[2].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[2].path);

    card[3].path = "c/fort.png";
    card[4].path = "c/fort.png";
    card[5].path = "c/fort.png";

    card[3].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[3].path);
    card[4].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[4].path);
    card[5].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[5].path);


    card[6].image = gtk_image_new ();
    card[7].image = gtk_image_new ();

    printf("card 0 address = %u\n", card[0].image);
    printf("card 6 address = %u\n", card[6].image);     

    card[8].path = pile[39];
    card[9].path = "c/mazzo.png";
    card[8].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[8].path);
    card[9].image = gtk_image_new_from_file (card[9].path);

    g_signal_connect (about_button, "clicked", G_CALLfort (activate_about), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (event_box1), "button_press_event", G_CALLfort (card1_clicked), card);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (event_box2), "button_press_event", G_CALLfort (card2_clicked), card);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (event_box3), "button_press_event", G_CALLfort (card3_clicked), card);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLfort (destroy), NULL);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (headbar), about_button);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_3);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_table);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), hbox_1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_2), card[8].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_2), card[9].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_1), event_box1);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_1), event_box2);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_1), event_box3);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (event_box1), card[0].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (event_box2), card[1].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (event_box3), card[2].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_3), card[3].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_3), card[4].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_3), card[5].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_table), card[6].image);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (hbox_table), card[7].image);   

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);

    gtk_main();

}

void card1_clicked (GtkWidget *window, struct my_image *card)
{
    printf("%s\n", card[0].path);
    card[6].image = card[0].image;
    /*gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(card[6].image), card[0].path);*/
}
```

the images initially are displayed correclty but when trigger `card1_clciked` this line `card[6].image = card[0].image;` produces a Segmentation Fault.
I'm not sure if I'm loading the image correctly and how to load another image using the same widget; I've also tried to use the function `/*gtk_image_set_from_file(GTK_IMAGE(card[6].image), card[0].path);*` with the same effect.

Comment: Where and how is `card` defined?

Comment: Did the `printf` show the correct result? Also: you have some typos in the code: `G_CALLfort` should be `G_CALLBACK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function for `button_press_event` signal is not defined properly.

The [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) tells us how it shall look like:

```
// The “button-press-event” signal

gboolean
user_function (GtkWidget *widget,
               GdkEvent  *event,
               gpointer   user_data)
```

In your function you are missing one parameter:

```
void card1_clicked (GtkWidget *window, struct my_image *card)
```

This means you are using the `event` pointer to read your `card` array which causes some illegal read access.

Besides that you do not provide the required boolean return value.

Comment: The callback signature looks fine for clicked signal, but for events (like button press in this case) there are not only one parameter missing. There is also the return type as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You are right. I extended the answer.